# Vim quickfix, using an existing file?

Tags: vim

There is a lot of documentation about vim's quickfix but I would like to know:

How I can I use a text file (or copy+paste from a terminal), and put this into a quick-fix list in vim?

All the docs I found so far assume that you run `make` or `vimgrep`, but in this case I just want to use a text file created elsewhere.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're looking for `:cfile` / `:cgetfile`:

> ```
>   :cf[ile][!] [errorfile] Read the error file and jump to the first error.
> ```

The file you're reading naturally must be in a format that can be parsed by the `'errorformat'` option.

Comment: Works well, heres a command I found to open vim with a quickfix and move to the last item (starting at the last and moving backwards often works best since edits may change line numbers) `gvim --nofork -c "cfile pep8.log" -c "cope" -c "clast"`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do  it is to change makeprog to cat from your text file, pretty sure there's a better way to do it though.