# Import/Load list of compiler warnings/errors to highlight in buffers?

Tags: vim

In vim you can start a build process using the `:make` command. Now I'd like to start the build process from outside of Vim (for example a nightly build) and load the compiler error/warning log, highlighting all the errors and warnings in the opened buffers.

Can Vim do this with built-in functionality or do I need a vimscript for that; and if so, which one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim quickfix, using an existing file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974140/vim-quickfix-using-an-existing-file)

Comment: You may also be interested in a related solution of how to run builds in the background. For this I suggest you take a look Tim Pope's dispatch.vim: https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch

Comment: @PeterRincker do you know how to make dispatch.vim load a particular `cfile` once the build finishes? Basically I want to run `:Make` and once that finishes do something like `silent execute 'cgetfile ' . fnameescape(some_log_file)` followed by `copen`. I read this [comment](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch/issues/40#issuecomment-19880381) but don't really understand it.

Comment: Sadly dispatch can not do callbacks so I do not think it will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `:cfile` / `:cgetfile`:

> ```
>   :cf[ile][!] [errorfile] Read the error file and jump to the first error.
> ```

The file you're reading naturally must be in a format that can be parsed by the `'errorformat'` option.

For Vimscript, there's also a `setqflist()` function.

### Highlighting

Once the errors are properly parsed in the *quickfix list*, there are a couple of plugins that can highlight the locations, for example the [cuteErrorMarker plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2653).

Comment: One can also populate it from [`grep`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#:cexpr) output: `:cexpr system('grep -n xyz *')`.