# How do I reload the quickfix window from a running Gvim?

Tags: windows, vim, vim-quickfix

Say I've got a file called `warnings.txt` that holds a list of doxygen warnings I want to inspect. In order to do this, I start Gvim (Win32 if that matters) from a command line using

```
gvim -q warnings.txt
```

Then, Gvim starts and I can start to process the warnings in the file.
After processing some of them, I want to re-create `warnings.txt`. I run doxygen again, the `warnings.txt` file gets refreshed.

Now, I want to read the refreshed `warnings.txt` and refresh the quickfix list.

How do I achieve this? How do I feed the quickfix window from a running Gvim?

Comment: `:cfile warnings.txt`

Comment: @SatoKatsura, you should post this as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vim quickfix, using an existing file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974140/vim-quickfix-using-an-existing-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:cfile` to reload the error file:

```
:cfile warnings.txt
```